# Multiple GETs in URL at the same time?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to GET variables out of an URL, but everytime the URL already has a query, it gets overwritten by the next query. Example:
I have a link;

```
<a href="?page=34">Page 34</a>
```

When you click on that link this link becomes visible;

```
<a href="?item=45">Item 45</a>
```

But when I click that link,  the other one get overwritten so the URL looks like;

> www.domainname.ext/?item45

But I want it to look like;

> www.domainname.ext/?page=34&item45

Any way to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within a given "page", you need to store the page ID and use that stored value when you create "item" links.

```
<?php
$pageID = $_GET['page'];

// ....

?>

<a href="?page=<?php echo $pageID; ?>&amp;item=45" title="Item 45">Item 45</a>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible with an easier way, like <a href=".&item=45">Item 45</a>?
And btw why '&amp;' instead of '&'

Comment: @Jay Wit: There is no way from the browser side to append to the query string, so no.  URLs are either absolute, starting from the base path, relative to the current direction, or relative to the current page when just the query string is specified.

Comment: @Jay Wit: In HTML (even in the string denoting an `href`), you have to provide `&` as a character entity (e.g., `&amp;`). HTML parsers are very forgiving about it, but it's technically wrong not to, and can in rare circumstances get you into trouble (e.g., if what follows the un-encoded `&` looks like it might be an entity name).

Comment: @Jay Wit: Character entities must be encoded when present in HTML, the ampersand character **&** is used to start entity encodings, so is a reserved character.  **&amp;** is the entity encoding for the ampersand character itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can also youse `http_build_query();` to append more params to your URL

```
$params = $_GET;
$params["item"] = 45;
$new_query_string = http_build_query($params);
```

[PHP http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

for instance:

```
$data = array('page'=> 34,
              'item' => 45);

echo http_build_query($data); //page=34&item=45
```

or include amp

```
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');  //page=34&amp;&item=45
```

Comment: @JayWit basically you can supply `http_build_query();` with an array full of the params you want, and it'll spit out the param part for you (part after the ?).

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="?page={$page->id}&amp;item={$item->id}">
    Page {$page->id}, Item {$item->id}
</a>
```

Comment: No sorry, the page id comes from the database so I can't do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

When outputting the links, you'll have to include *all* of the relevant query string parameters; there's no automatic "merge".

If you could change your server-side stuff to using [RESTful URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), you could get this sort of behavior. E.g., starting with

```
http://www.domainname.ext
```

this link

```
<a href='page34'>Page 34</a>
```

would take you to

```
http://www.domainname.ext/page34
```

after which this link

```
<a href='item43'>Item 43</a>
```

would take you to

```
http://www.domainname.ext/page34/item43
```

...but that requires quite a big change in your server-side stuff.